# Delete (x) 3 last rows in columns with bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have text file with data in columns. I want to delete x number of rows in one or more columns.
My original file looks:

```
Column.1    Column.2    Column.3    Column.4    Column.5
dhd21       393j        A/B/C/      1224        ouiyt
nvd0        8ncbb       E/F/G       125a        b09bv
xnxb        x9jd        m/f/e/      ljkjh       bhh66
hyru        jsdj        M7D7W7Q7    mnuy        bbbb
098y        sa56        by6         hhgt        xghsh
```

I want the output to look like this, *(e.g removed 3 rows from column 2 and 4 from column 4)*:

```
Column.1    Column.2    Column.3    Column.4    Column.5
dhd21       393j        A/B/C/      1224        ouiyt
nvd0        8ncbb       E/F/G                   b09bv
xnxb                    m/f/e/                  bhh66
hyru                    M7D7W7Q7                bbbb
098y                    by6                     xghsh
```

I have code to take a whole column:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2,3 delims=  " %%B in (in.txt) do @echo %%B  %%C >> out.txt
```

Comment: In order to maintain column spacing, you really need to think about the task as replacing each non space character in those columns with space characters. That said, can you please explain the process of determining which columns and which rows require manipulation and your reason for using only the batch-file tag. The StackOverflow community doesn't consist of out of work script writers, all willing to work for free on other peoples tasks, especially when they've shown little to no effort themselves, you are supposed show your attempts at writing your own code, what you've submitted doesn't.

Comment: I apologize for not fixing the correct formatting. In my original text file there is <tab> between columns. I just copied from my text file and pasted directly.  Thank you for formatting column fields so they look the right way!

Comment: If there are tabs in the original file, it is important that we know more about that file, not just look at a non representative example.

Comment: I create my own text file and try to learn. I'm really trying to do this myself with extra FOR loop, or SET new variable but I did not manage this. I really respect you at the StackOverflow community and are grateful for all your help!

Comment: If you've created your own problem and don't have the knowledge or experience to come up with a solution, perhaps you should set yourself less difficult problems, or break the problem into smaller steps, dealing with each in turn before trying to join them into this tricky solution. Creating a problem for somebody else to fix is no different to asking for a freelance tutor and script writer, for those things Stack Overflow is not the appropriate forum for you.

Comment: I'm really sorry and do not understand why you criticize me so hard. I just asked one question I want to learn. I've been helped earlier by you without being criticized. I do not have the knowledge to know if a question is easy or difficult. I'm really sorry and thank you for all the help I've got before! I'm really sorry!

Comment: All of your previous questions remain not accepted by you, _and I've spent my time answering at least two of them_. Ignoring solutions or not marking them as accepted doesn't help this site, doesn't motivate potential responders and doesn't indicate that you are a particularly grateful for what you may be directly or indirectly learning.

Comment: I have never ignored, or have not been grateful for all the help I have received. It is sad that we are discussing this way. You are respected from my side. Thanks for all your help

Comment: There are no accepted answers on any of them, that is the in-place system for showing your gratitude. One of your questions, _which I also had to edit_, ignoring several several deleted comments there still remain 23 _(over a period of more than 27 hours)_, that's a lot of time exhausted. Saying you're grateful at some time later doesn't really justify your inability to mark answers as accepted. If those answers weren't to your satisfaction, then you should have updated them with your own solutions as answers or updated the questions with better or more current information for further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in batch with sqlite3.exe. If you do not have sqlite3
already, then you can get it from the Sqlite [download](https://sqlite.org/download.html) page.
It is a small standalone executable file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

sqlite3 ^
-cmd "create table t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)" ^
-cmd ".mode tab" ^
-cmd ".import test.csv t1" ^
-cmd "update t1 set c4 = '' where c1 = 'nvd0'" ^
-cmd "update t1 set c2 = '', c4 = '' where c1 = 'xnxb'" ^
-cmd "update t1 set c2 = '', c4 = '' where c1 = 'hyru'" ^
-cmd "update t1 set c2 = '', c4 = '' where c1 = '098y'" ^
-cmd ".separator \"\t\" \"\r\n\"" ^
-cmd ".once output.csv" ^
-cmd "select * from t1" ^
":memory:" ""

echo Done
```

Since the command is long, the use of `^` at end of lines is to continue
the command to the next line.

The table `t1` is created in memory with 5 columns. `.mode tab` and
`.import test.csv t1` allows for the action of importing from file
`test.csv` with tab separators and insert into table `t1`.

Four updates are done to the rows in the table where `c1` = (*value to match*).
Columns 2 or 4 or both may be set as a empty string if the condition is met.

`.separator`... sets tabs as separators and CRLF as end of lines for ouput.
`.once`... sets the output file as `output.csv` for the next sql command to
be handled only once.

`select * from t1` prints all rows and all columns for table `t1`.

`:memory:` tells sqlite3 to use a memory database instead of a file.
The following empty quotes are just an empty sql statement so the
sqlite3 will close without interaction.

Note: Use of double quotes inside double quoted arguments, a `\` can escape
the double quotes that are within i.e. `"\"abc\""` is stripped of outer
quotes by the interpreter and thus you are left with a quoted string `"abc"`.